# Insufficient SQL database permissions for user ""

Tags: 2007, search, permissions, database

I'm working with SharePoint 2007 and when I start the search service I keep getting the following error:

```
Insufficient SQL database permissions for user '' in database Test_ConfigDB on SQL Server instance test. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.

EXECUTE permission denied on object 'proc_getNewObjects',database 'SharePoint_Config', schema 'dbo'.
```

The strange thing is where it says "for user", there is no user.

I've had a look at the search service in Central Admin and defined a search user, so why is it not picking it up?

Thanks

Comment: This means the service account that you are using to provision SharePoint Search does not have db owner rights on the SharePoint Configuration database. Have you provisioned a separate service account for Search ?

Comment: @MossFarmer I have provisioned a separate search service account which I referenced in the search service settings. I can also confirm that the search service account does have db owner rights on the SharePoint configuration database.

Comment: @MossFarmer Just an update, the search does work, it's just the error that I can't seem to get rid of in the Event Viewer,it appears in intervals of one minute.

Comment: Can you then add  the account to these server roles in SQL: "Securityadmin and dbccreator".

Comment: @MossFarmer I've just checked, the account already has both of those roles. Any other ideas?

Comment: When you stop the search service do you still get this error in regular intervals ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3812/discussion-between-moss-farmer-and-imran-azad)

Comment: @MossFarmer They still appear even after having stopped the service! Why is that?

Comment: @MossFarmer I'm unable to continue in chat as it requires 20 reputation points.